# Login doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

so, I'm trying to make a login form but I'm facing an error..
It doesn't continue, it shows only no data (the error message I've put if the username or password is incorrect, even tho I;ve set them correct)

this is my code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BRZAP\\MSSQLSERVERBTK; Initial Catalog=BrzAP; Integrated Security=True;");
try
{
    conn.Close();
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT id,d_username,d_password FROM t_Login 
                            WHERE d_username=@usr AND 
                            d_password=@pw", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", txtUID.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", txtP.ToString());
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
       MessageBox.Show(reader["d_username"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no data");
    } 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    conn.Close();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

bellow is a pic of the data I have in sql. 
[pic with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBOuH.png)

Comment: I also tried to remove the parameters and do it without them.. still the same thing.. also, password box is set on purpose as a textbox. for now

Comment: Are txtUID and txtP `TextBox`?

Comment: yes they are. tried on hardcodding the intro same still..

Comment: In that case, see my answer below.

Comment: txtUID.ToString()  has the actual value or empty string?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `txtUID.Text` and `txtP.Text` instead of `txtUID.ToString()` and `txtP.ToString()`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", txtUID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", txtP.Text);
```

The `Text` property gives you the actual value in the text box. But when you call `.ToString()` on a `TextBox` control, you will get something like:

> System.Windows.Controls.Textbox

This means that the parameter will always be incorrect.

[See the documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)